# Footer links not displaying on homepage but are displaying on all others

Tags: hyperlink, footer, invisible

My social footer links are not visible on the home page but they are visible on all other pages of the website. How can I fix this to make them visible on my home page?

Comment: I had found this on the web which kind of fixed the problem but the linked in icon isn't the same on all pages.  css- .fa {
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome !important;
} - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/footer-icons-not-showing-up-on-homepage/

Comment: It would be good to edit that information into your question.